# create pdf from dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

Can someone help me out with creating a PDF on the iPad? The data in the app is stored in an NSMutableDictionary. The data is only strings that people enter at times in the app. At the end of the app I need to collect all this data and format it nicely with a header created by an image. My concern is that the data will longer for some people and I don't want to overflow the pdf. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html).

Comment: I have read that and I am having a hard time with it. The code provided generates an error. Is there an example that someone could point me to that uses the current os? thanks

Comment: It does use the current os. Unfortunately, it's a really hard process.